# Command not found when calling a command inside a variable

Tags: bash

I'm starting to learn programming and decide to start with shell.
Here's a script i wrote to take screenshots using the scrot command.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Take a screenshot and save with date

D=$(date +%Y%m%d)   # grab the date
SC_DIR=~/Pictures/Screenshots   # save to this directory
scrotcmd=$(scrot)

# this function will check if the file exists and append a number in front of it.

cheese() {
    if [[ -e "$SC_DIR"/scr-"$D".png ]] ; then
        i=1
        while [[ -e "$SC_DIR"/scr-"$D"-"$i".png ]] ; do
            i=$((i+1))
        done
        "$scrotcmd" -q 90 "$SC_DIR"/scr-"$D"-"$i".png
    else
        "$scrotcmd" -q 90 "$SC_DIR"/scr-"$D".png
    fi
}

case $1 in
    s)
        scrotcmd=$(scrot -s)        # select a region for the screenshot
        cheese
        ;;
    w)
        scrotcmd=$(scrot -u -b)     # focused window only
        cheese
        ;;
    *)
        scrotcmd=$(scrot)           # entire screen
        cheese
        ;;
esac
```

When i run it, it gives me this:
scrot: line 16: : command not found

Why it isn't calling the command inside $scrotcmd var?

Comment: `scrotcmd=$(scrot)` - you want execute the command `scrot` here or, like, save the string `scrot` into a variable to execute it later? `Why it isn't calling the command inside $scrotcmd var?` - there is no command there, there is the output from the  execution of a command.

Comment: Save to execute later. I was setting the variable to the command in the beginning of the script just to be safe. The scrotcmd should be the command i need to run (in this case the scrot command).

Comment: `I was setting the variable to the command in the beginning of the script just to be safe` - No. You were _executing_ the command at the beginning of the script and setting the variable to the standard output coming from the execution of the command. `$( ... )` - means _execute_ the command and grab the output from it. Ie. `str=$(echo 1)`. Much like `D=$(date +%Y%m%d)`. That does not mean you can later do `$D` to execute `date` again. `$D` only stores the output of `date` execution.

Comment: Oh i see. Changing it to "scrot" solved the issue. But now i'm having a issue with "scrot -s" and "scrot -u -b". It says command no found.

Comment: Leave out the quotes: `$scrotcmd` instead of `"$scrotcmd"`

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked!

Comment: @Grand0rbiter That's because `"$scrotcmd"` is interpreted as one command name, space including. So the shell tries to execute a file named `scrot -u -b` exactly, with spaces in the filename. As there is no command named `scrot -u -b`, bash returns command not found.+

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `scrot` from  `scrotcmd` variable, you have to do

```
scrotcmd="scrot"
```

Because `scrotcmd=$(scrot)` executes `scrot` and puts output to `scrotcmd` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to use bash arrays to handle any unescaped strange strings

```
...
scrotcmd=(scrot)
...
cheese() {
     ...
     # is properly expanded, as the input
     # so the spaces and all unreadable characters are preserved as in the input
     "${scrotcmd[@]}" -q 90 "$SC_DIR"/scr-"$D"-"$i".png
     ...
}
...
scrotcmd=(scrot -a -u "arg with spaces")
...
```

You can get away with just strings, but it is unsafe and I would advise away from it:

```
...
scrotcmd="scrot"
...
cheese() {
     ...
     # this is unsafe
     # the content of the variable $scrotcmd is reexpanded
     # so arguments with spaces will not work as intended
     # cause space will intepreted as command separator
     $scrotcmd -q 90 "$SC_DIR"/scr-"$D"-"$i".png
     ...
}
...
scrotcmd="scrot -a"
...
```